# eslint for loop 'i' is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I am pretty new to eslint and I am updating my code to fit my eslint file.

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    node: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: 'eslint:recommended',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
  },
  rules: {
    indent: ['error', 2],
    'linebreak-style': ['error', 'unix'],
    quotes: ['error', 'single'],
    semi: ['error', 'always'],
  },
};
```

I have a for loop and eslint is saying that 'i' is not defined.

```js
  for (i = 0; dbl.length > i; i++) {
    arr.push(dbl[i].Author); 
  }
```

To my knowledge when using a for loop you are supposed to init a var in the first part, however I'm not sure.

Am I doing for loops wrong or is there something I am missing with eslint?

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the variable first. Follow the code below.

```html
  for (let i = 0; dbl.length > i; i++) {
    arr.push(dbl[i].Author); 
  }
```

I think you got the point.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is unrelated to eslint. You need to define `i` before you can use it.

```js
// note the `let` before the `i`
for (let i = 0; dbl.length > i; i++) {
    arr.push(dbl[i].Author); 
}
```

Comment: This is the same as Jaied's answer.

Comment: Look like we wrote at the same time then

Comment: Okay. Anyway, the question is closed.